# Navigation drawer not showing on screen

Tags: python, kivy

I don't know what is wrong. No errors but Navigation Drawer not showing

below is the python source: mainmenu.py

```
from kivy import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer

class Drawer(NavigationDrawer):
    pass

class MainMenuApp(App):

    def show_drawer(self):
        d = Drawer()
        d.toggle_state()

    def build(self):
        return DrawerBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainMenuApp().run()
```

below the kivy language source: mainmenu.kv

```
<Drawer>:
    title: "Main Menu"
    BoxLayout:
        orientaion: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "1"
        Button:
            text: "1"
        Button:
            text: "1"
        Button:
            text: "1"
        Button:
            text: "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem. I read the documentation again. Navigation Drawer has two panels-side panel and main panel-i only created side panel.

Below my correction:

mainmenu.py

```
from kivy import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer

class Drawer(NavigationDrawer):
    pass

class MainMenuApp(App):

    def show_drawer(self):
        d = Drawer()
        d.toggle_state()

    def build(self):
        return Drawer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainMenuApp().run()
```

mainmenu.kv

```
<Drawer>:
title: "Main Menu"

# Side panel
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "Button 1"
    Button:
        text: "Button 2"
    Button:
        text: "Button 3"

# Main panel
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "Show Side Panel"
        on_press: root.toggle_state()
```